# Is it possible to use ReSharper with Blend?

Tags: resharper, blend

I'd like to use ReSharper with Blend, as I do with Visual Studio. For some reason I can't seem to find any information online that explains how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible, you may vote for [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-428030).